# Rails: many to many relationship - creating and associating new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I'm looking at this [railscast #17 revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?view=comments) as a tutorial to create a many to many relationship between two models using a join table:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :courselocalizations
has_many :courselocations, through: :courselocalizations
end

class Courselocation < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :courselocalizations
has_many :courses, through: :courselocalizations
end

class Courselocalization < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :course
belongs_to :courselocation
end
```

If the user doesn't see an existing `courselocation` when editing or creating the `course`, what's the best way for them to create a new `courselocation` and automatically make the association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do this in a 2 step process (my preferred method), or in a single step.

2 step process:
 - Create the `CourseLocation`
 - Associate the `CourseLocation` and `Course`.

```rb
course_location1 = CourseLocation.create(name: 'location1')
course.course_locations << course_location1
```

---

---

If you want to do this in 1 step it is possible using the Active Record `accepts_nested_attributes_for` [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), this is a little tricky.  Here is a [good article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through) on it but let's break the steps down:

1. A course needs to accept attributes for course_localizations
2. A course localization needs to accept attributes for course_location
3. When creating a course, pass the attributes for a localization which contains the attributes for a location.

Lets set all that up for your particular case:

```rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attribute subject
  has_many :course_localizations, inverse_of: :course
  has_many :course_locations, through: :course_localizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_localizations
end

class CourseLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attribute city
  has_many :course_localizations
  has_many :courses, through: :course_localizations
end

class CourseLocalization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :course_location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_locations
end
```

At this point you should be able to

```rb
course = Course.new(
  subject: "Math",
  course_localizations_attributes: [
    { course_location_attributes: { city: "Los Angeles" } },
    { course_location_attributes: { city: "San Francisco" } }]
)

course.save
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up testing `accepts_nested_attributes_for` using a form builder on the `course` new/edit views and adding `1.times {@course.courselocations.build}` within the course controller's new action. What I'll end up doing is loading the form via ajax if there isn't already a course location present.

What's the purpose of adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_locations` to the `courselocalizations` model?

Comment: It makes it explicit that you can pass `course_location` attributes into the `course_localizations` model and they will be passed through to the `course_locations`.  You have to pass the attributes 2 layers deep.  If you're already setting up the ajax, I would seriously consider not using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and just making 2 separate API requests.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks  - what's the downside of using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in an ajax form? Also, I guess I'm not clear how I would use the two step process you mention above if that's what you're referring to as the 2 separate API requests.

Comment: Actually, are you suggesting that the create action for course include @course.courselocations << Courselocation.new() ?

Comment: We are getting into my opinions here but I don't like `accepts_nested_attributes_for` because it requires you to deal with data from many models as once and I find it harder to work on.  Yes I was referring to 2 separate api calls.